# Django doesn't load build/static files ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, django, django-staticfiles

Hello I have try make a website using ReactJS and Django with RESTAPI. When i run `npm start` and `python manage.py runserver`
separatly that work perfectly. But when i try to render the index.html with django from the react/build. The files that return 404 exists. It doesn't work. It render a blank page with the errors:

My folders:

[image: folder images]

[image: terminal log]

There is my files.

settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "127.0.0.1"
]


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'polluser.apps.PolluserConfig',
    'restapi.apps.RestapiConfig',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
]

SITE_ID = 1 

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'template.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'template.wsgi.application'
...

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="build/index.html")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('restapi.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Did you copy those files from bundler output to django static folder? Do you run them together with nginx/apache? If not then static/media urlpatterns are missing in your urls.py

Comment: First question.

Comment: Please some help. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `python manage.py collectstatic` command once and check.

Error 404 occur when you request a resource which is not present in the location you are pointing. make sure the request files to be present in `<your-project>/static/` folder. `static/` directory is along side `manage.py` file.

[image]

If you are passing authorization header in API request. Then make sure it is not forwarded in other request server make to fetch static resource. (Try making request on page without authorization in header and see if same error occurs.)

If you are required to pass authorization to access those resouce then try passing authorization in request header.

Comment: I have make no authorization. I have check 5 times but it doesn't render.

Comment: I am not able to figure out why there is some suffix in the filename. Like GET request can be directly to `/static/js/main.js` or `/static/js/main.chunk.js` but there is some random text lke `main.dac16c5c.chunk.js`. 
One thing is sure here 404 error means requested resource is not present.
1. Either the request is try to reach some random resource.
2. Request is correct but resource is not present in the location.
resource = static files (here)

Comment: The resources exist.

Comment: I run the command  `python manage.py findstatic` on of the file. It doesn't recognize the file.

Comment: I deploy my site with pythonanywhere and it worked.